# Excel - How to add a file selection button to a cell?

Tags: excel

I am creating a model that requires the user to enter into certain cells the addresses of required spreadsheets, folders etc that the model uses.

Rather than have the user cut and paste the addresses in, I was hoping to include some kind of form control in the cell itself that would prompt the user to browse for the file and then return the filepath to the cell once the user had selected 'ok'.

Is there a standard Windows form control that will acheive this? It feels like there should be but all I can find are toggle buttons, drop-down menus etc?

I know I can write a custom script to capture the double_click event, any pointers on a more 'native' way to do it would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: `Application.GetOpenFilename("Word Documents (*.doc), *.doc")` opens the common file dialog with filters set to Word .doc files, for example. Add it to your `Button_Click` event.

Answer (score 5):

You can connect a form button to the file open dialog.

This allows a user to select a file, but you do not have to open it.

```
Sub GetFile()

Dim varFile As Variant

varFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xls), *.xls", , "Select a file", , False)
If varFile = False Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    ActiveCell.Value2 = varFile
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: To remove the filter and show all types of file, use: 
`Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Select a file", , False)`